# UBER Unable to complete Oauth process

Tags: uber-api

I am working on integrating the UBER API into my app.
The first step goes fine : an Authorization url is created, the user is redirected to Uber, logs in, accepts to share the desired scope, then UBER redirects to my redirection url as provided in the dashboard and in the authorization url.

When then I make a POST request to 
https://login.uber.com/oauth/v2/token
 to obtain an access token

Here is the payload I send to Uber on this url

```
{
    "code": "obtained_from_redirection_url",
    "client_id": "XXXXXXX",
    "client_secret": "XXXXXXX",
    "redirect_uri": "https://myredirection-url.me",
    "grant_type": "authorization_code",
    "scope": "all_trips history history_lite places profile request request_receipt ride_widgets" 
}
```

the response is always

```
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

As you can see, the grant_type : **authorization_code** value is the one provided by Uber.

The scope you see here, is exactly the same as the one sent with the authorization url.

So We can at least say that the error shown does not correspond to what causes the problem, which remains a mystery to me.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Possibly the issue is "ride_widgets" -- as you can see from the documentation that product is deprecated: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/widget/introduction

Comment: This happens regardless of the scope. I tried with only one scope at a time and I get always the same error

Comment: @KyleDavis any new on this topic? I have really tried every scope separately with no success. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know-- I am not able to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can we at least explain why it is returning "error": "unsupported_grant_type" when the payload has a correct grant_type. Is there a way I can raise a ticket with Uber dev team?

Comment: @KyleDavis any news on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer to this issue was that the token endpoint expects the POST request to be made with a `Content-Type = x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of JSON.
It is not documented in UBER's doc, and I wish it was cause it made me loose days and days seeking a solution.